# filter user input in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I built something in angular using ng-repeat

```
            <ul class="messages">
                <li ng-repeat="e in enquiries">
                    <img src="/img/avatar.jpg" alt="">
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <h5>{{e.user}}</h5>
                            <span class="time"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> {{e.created_at}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <p>{{e.post}}</p>
                        <div ng-if="e.is_replied == 'no'"><a href="/hub/delete">Delete</a></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

This is to display the inputs by users. However i did not `htmlentities` to encode the user input but directly insert the user input into database such as `<a href="jscode">Hack</a>` However i notice when i display this message using above code. it will still display the message as `<a href="jscode">Hack</a>` instead of display a "`hack`" link. can i say in this case angular will auto sanitize the input? Should i still need to use "ng-bind-html"?

Comment: angular expressions are treated as text

Answer (score 0):

If your post content is HTML you will need to change to ng-bind-html:

```
<p ng-bind-html="e.post | to_trusted"></p>
```

Also you will need a filter to sanitize:

```
app.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}])
```

Comment: so you mean if i dont do this way, it will be unsafe? sorry i am still new to angular

Comment: Yes you are correct. If you do not use the filter, angular will throw error saying tis unsafe

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is the [$sanitize](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/docs/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize) service, part of the `ngSanitize` module. Use the `ng-bind-html` directive, which automatically uses `$sanitize`. `ng-bind-html` will insert your text *as* raw HTML, but only if it's in the `ngSanitize` white list of safe HTML. If you're absolutely sure the HTML is safe (e.g., if you sanitize it on the back end), there's a way to tell Angular to stuff it in as is, regardless of the white list.

Comment: actually i dont do santize on the backend now. that means if i leave it be as in my question, my app will be unsecure?

Comment: If you use `ngSanitize` along with `ng-bind-html`, your app should be fine. Angular will allow raw HTML if the HTML is in the `ngSanitize` white list (which, I believe, `<a>` is). If the tag is a "dangerous" tag (i.e., not in the white list), such as `<script>`, then `ngSanitize` will escape it. Read the documentation for `ngSanitize` carefully. It does what you want.